# Can't change folder background

Tags: gui, themes, folder

I tried to change via dragging from the Backgrounds and Emblems window, but the icon just goes back to that window rather than changing the folder background.However, I can change the task bar by this drag-n-drop.

Probably it is something about changing ownership permission? if so how to change that?

In /home/mashruf/.gconf/apps/nautilus/preferences/%gconf.xml file it says:, Should I change this file? how?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
    <entry name="click_policy" mtime="1297597800" type="string">
        <stringvalue>single</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="default_folder_viewer" mtime="1297597336" type="string">
        <stringvalue>list_view</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="media_autorun_x_content_open_folder" mtime="1297534321" type="list" ltype="string">
    </entry>
    <entry name="media_autorun_x_content_ignore" mtime="1297534321" type="list" ltype="string">
    </entry>
    <entry name="media_autorun_x_content_start_app" mtime="1297534321" type="list" ltype="string">
        <li type="string">
            <stringvalue>x-content/software</stringvalue>
        </li>
    </entry>
    <entry name="start_with_location_bar" mtime="1297300028" type="bool" value="true"/>
    <entry name="side_pane_view" mtime="1297269334" type="string">
        <stringvalue>NautilusTreeSidebar</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="navigation_window_saved_maximized" mtime="1297600306" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <entry name="navigation_window_saved_geometry" mtime="1297600306" type="string">
        <stringvalue>964x608+59+2</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="sidebar_width" mtime="1297390418" type="int" value="192"/>
</gconf>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there is a much easier way to achieve what you would like to do.

- Open Nautilus
- Right Click on a Folder
- Click on Properties
- Click on the Folder Icon Button (yes it's really a button!)
- Browse to the image you would like to replace it with

  /usr/share/pixmaps

are where most of the standard icons are stored

- Select the image you would like to use

(see the images below)

*On a side note.* Never try to edit the gconf files by hand in the XML it's completely unnecessary and very easy to nuke your entire desktop/gnome configuration.
Instead use the GUI(Graphical User Interface) tool gconf-editor. Ubuntu-Key (Super) then type in gconf and choose the Configuration Editor. It works very similar to the Windows(R)(tm)(c) registry editor (gasp).

*For your third question* on File Permissions you can right-click in Nautilus, Choose Properties and change the permissions under the Permissions tab.
Or you can change the permissions on the command line using the chmod command
see this [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) document on File Permissions
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

[image: choose Properties]

[image: Folder Properties]

[image: usr share pixmaps]

[image: icon changed]
[image: Ubuntu Logo as Folder Icon]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at $HOME/.gconf/apps/nautilus/preferences

Comment: @newcomer Update your question with the things you try, that way they don't get buried in comments.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited question..

Comment: Hello. Nautilus has of course to set the file mentioned. Maybe the file or its path is not writeable (please check that first).

Comment: I selected the marble-background and the file was updated  <entry name="background_set" mtime="1297621963" type="bool" value="true"/>
 <entry name="background_filename" mtime="1297621963" type="string">
  <stringvalue>file:///usr/share/nautilus/patterns/purple_marble.png</stringvalue>
 </entry> You can eventually alter the file with a dummy-operation (using gedit or geany) and try to save the "modifications" made. If ok, then nautilus must be able to do the same thing!